# run scrpts on routers with BusyBox

Tags: router, telnet, busybox

I own a router (tp link w8960n) that I can "control" via telnet and busybox.
Is it possible to create and run a script on the router like a permanent process(more like a cronojob) if the router has busybox? is it like an OS?
I couldn't a find a way since I have a limited set of commands I can use.

Thank you

Comment: a startup script?

Comment: yes that would do it, something that I could keep running.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading you default firmware to OpenWrt firmware.
It provides more functions then the default routers firmware.
openwrt.org